# Javascript Tree Structure to Array conversion

Tags: javascript

I am working on a treeview and I build a simple Node-Class: It consists of a name and an array of children:

```
class Node {
  constructor(name, childNodes) {
    this.name = name;
    this.childNodes = childNodes;
  }
}
```

Now my aim is to create a function that returns an object like this:

```
var tree = [
  {
    text: 'Parent 1',
    nodes: [
      {
        text: 'Child 1',
        nodes: [
          {
            text: 'Grandchild 1'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Child 2'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: 'Parent 2'
  },
];
```

I tried using a recursive method. It starts with an empty array and adds children until there are no more left:

```
function recTreeview(currentNode, treeview) {
  var tempChildren = [];
  currentNode.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    tempChild.push(recTreeview(child, treeview));
  });
  return treeview.push({
    text: currentNode.name,
    nodes: tempChildren
  })
}
```

But something with the recursive Treeview Function has to be wrong. When I create the tree and try to open it in the chrome dev console, it just shows a "5" instead of something like (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]. What did I do wrong?

```
tree = recTreeview(parent, []);
tree;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the result of the `push` and not the actual `treeview`.

As per the [`Array.prototype.push()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> **Return value**
>     The new `length` property of the object upon which the method was called.

---

So instead of `return treeview.push(...)` do `treeview.push(...)` and then `return treeview`

```
function recTreeview(currentNode, treeview) {
  var tempChildren = [];
  currentNode.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    tempChild.push(recTreeview(child, treeview));
  });
  treeview.push({
    text: currentNode.name,
    nodes: tempChildren
  });

  return treeview;
}
```